# select row till which sum less than 25 of count_visitor column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
visitor_keyword                    count_visitor

Homepage                                14
Web developing                           6
Page Mobile application                  4
Developing websites for ipad             3
Android developing                       2
Android developing in new hampshire      2
Android development                      2
```

I want the output upto the sum of the count_visitor column is 25 from first row

ie: the output we get is only top 3rows

My sql query is

```
select visitor_keyword, COUNT(visitor_keyword) AS count_visitor
from handlegraph
group by visitor_keyword
order by count_visitor DESC
```

Comment: And the wanted result is? BTW, you know that rows are unordered unless ORDER BY is specified?

Comment: `group by visitor_keyword having count(count_visitor) <25` is what you want

Comment: You should explain, whether this is a programming question, the environment you use to develop, whatever you've tried. Your codes that causing problem.

Comment: my sql query is 
>>>
select  visitor_keyword,COUNT(visitor_keyword) AS count_visitor 
from handlegraph group by visitor_keyword  order by count_visitor DESC

Comment: And now you only want rows where count_visitor is less than 25?

Comment: And what is the desired output?

Comment: Or are you creating a running sum? i.e. Return Up to and including Page Mobile application because 14+6+4 < 25 but +3 from Developing websi isn't?

Comment: voting for close, there is no question here

Comment: hey guys he want the output upto the sum of the count_visitor column is 25 from first row

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Then you should use `having` keyword.

```
select visitor_keyword, COUNT(visitor_keyword) AS count_visitor
from handlegraph
group by visitor_keyword
having count(visitor_keyword) < 25
order by visitor_keyword DESC
```

Comment: Please post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

I  assume that, after performing a `GROUP BY`, you want to return all groups up to the point that the `SUM` of `count_visitor` aggregate reaches 25. If you are using SQL Server 2012+, you can use `SUM() OVER()` to calculate the running total of `count_visitor`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT visitor_keyword, COUNT(visitor_keyword) AS count_visitor
   FROM handlegraph
   GROUP BY visitor_keyword
)
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT visitor_keyword, count_visitor, 
          SUM(count_visitor) OVER (ORDER BY count_visitor DESC) AS s
   FROM CTE ) t
WHERE t.s < 25
ORDER BY count_visitor DESC
```

You can use the following query for SQL SERVER 2008 R2 or earlier versions:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT visitor_keyword, 
          COUNT(visitor_keyword) AS count_visitor, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(visitor_keyword) DESC) AS rn
   FROM handlegraph
   GROUP BY visitor_keyword
)
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT visitor_keyword, count_visitor, (SELECT SUM(count_visitor) 
                                           FROM CTE c2
                                           WHERE c2.rn <= c1.rn) AS s
   FROM CTE AS c1 ) t
WHERE t.s < 25
ORDER BY count_visitor DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will helps you..

It will restricts the data when the sum exceeds 25

```
with cte_a as
(

 select visitor_keyword   from handlegraph
)

select sum(tbl2.count_visitor), visitor_keyword 
from cte_c as tbl1
inner join handlegraph as tbl2
on tbl2.visitor_keyword   =tbl1.visitor_keyword   
group by tbl1.visitor_keyword   
having sum(tbl2.count_visitor)<25
```

---